# Should a twisted copper pipe be replaced?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, copper

While replacing a hot water tank I foolishly twisted the out pipe by losing my grip on the wrench.

The copper pipe twisted, so I twisted it back gently, but it now has a kink in it. Is this likely to suddenly split open? As it is the outflow pipe for the hot water it will become hot.

I've cut the water, and will be away for a week, so is this something I should get a plumber to look at urgently?

Any input welcome.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like you twisted it hard enough to strain the metal much, so it's not likely to break on you. However, you did narrow the cross section enough to create a nasty flow restrictor. That *could* be a problem for you.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - thanks for the comment. I was thinking of trying to squeeze the pipe to get rid of the kink, but thought it could weaken it more.

Comment: Agreed. I would not touch this until you are back to repair it. Copper has a nasty habit for tearing. At this time, the pipe looks safe.

Comment: related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/76068/should-i-replace-a-kinked-hot-water-supply-pipe

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Wayfaring... You probably haven't structurally weakened the pipe, but you have created a flow restriction.  If you can live with that, then so be it.

But since it's on the hot side, it's very simple to isolate.  Why not just turn off the valve to the water heater and replace the damaged section?