# Can you repair a kinked copper pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, copper-tubing

I have a copper water pipe which has a mild kink in it, very similar to this photo, not even quite as severe:

[image]

It is hard copper.

The kink itself is not causing any problems but in the future I may need to do some work in this area and I'm concerned that it might make working with fittings near the kink difficult, especially since the pipe may need to be cut back a bit closer to the defect.

Obviously one option is to replace the kinked section, and that might be the best course of action.

But is there a method to attempt to restore the correct shape of the pipe? This seems worth at least trying first before taking on a much more laborious replacement. Especially if there is, say, a $15 special tool or something that could do the job and save a few hours work.

Thanks

Comment: related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/76068/should-i-replace-a-kinked-hot-water-supply-pipe

Comment: related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58023/should-a-twisted-copper-pipe-be-replaced

Answer (score 2):

If you can drain the pipe, then you could heat the pipe with a blow torch and using some long handle pliers or pipe grips gently "persuade" the kink out... You have to have patience.

But if it is not severe then leave well alone and **don't** bend it any more.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it alone. It's not restricting flow so no need to mess with it. you might, and probably will, make the problem worse.

Comment: It need to be dealt with one way or another eventually, due to the future work to be done. The reason for asking for specific methods to un-kink it is to avoid making it worse.

Comment: If it can be put off until you do the other work, great. If not, cutting out the kink and replacing it with a new section of pipe is a fairly easy repair.